# String splitting in R()

Tags: r

I have an email in a .txt format. I'm trying to split the various words that consist the email in different element of a vector.

I am using this method and it kinda works ( still have to improve the reg expr )

```
corpus <- url %>% 
  paste(readLines("H:/Spam/prova.txt"), collapse=" ") %>% 
  gsub("H:/Spam/prova.txt", "", .)

head(corpus)

z <- corpus %>% 
  gsub(" +", " ", .) %>% 
  strsplit(split = "[\\a-zA-Z0-9':!?$€.] ")

z[[1]]
```

The only problem about this algorithm is that its cutting out the last letter of every word it encounters, and I seem not to be able to fix it since my lack of experience in R

An example of output:

```
[1039] "N"                                                                          "   operato"                                                                
[1041] "pleas"                                                                      "leav"                                                                      
[1043] "you"                                                                        "nam"                                                                       
[1045] "phon"                                                                       "numbe"                                                                     
[1047] "an"                                                                         "bes"                                                                       
[1049] "tim"                                                                        "N"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: how about using the stringr package. It has a command called word that does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't know how to use it, could you provide me an example?

Comment: As you provided no example data and have since responded since the request i am voting to close.

Comment: The example is in my result. The email is a standard email Return-Path: <z6hHv7SU7@server.stardot.ca>
Delivered-To: bfsmedia-design@bfsmedia.com
Received: (qmail 9568 invoked from network); 2 Feb 2001 01:34:57 -0000
Received: from ns.vuolijoki.fi (HELO vuolijokint.vuolijoki.fi) (212.116.62.10)
  by bfsmedia.sk.ca with SMTP; 2 Feb 2001 01:34:57 -0000
Received: from bqvP32489 (1Cust26.tnt8.denver.co.da.uu.net [63.14.59.26]) by vuolijokint.vuolijoki.fi with SMTP (Microsoft Exchange

Comment: Please edit your original question. In case you're new to stackoverflow, take 15 minutes to look around, filter questions by their score, look at some high ranking questions and learn from them.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, turns out I was not entirely correct. Stringr is the right place. It is just different command...

```
library(stringr)
text_sample<-"After talks in Damascus on Tuesday, the UN special envoy to Syria, Staffan de Mistura, said the Syrian government had a duty to allow access to whoever needed it."
result<-str_extract_all(text_sample,"\\w+")
```

Is this what you are looking for? Let me know if that works...

**Edit**
I quickly benchmarked both methods. stri_extract_all_words is faster...

```
library(stringi)
library(stringr)
library(microbenchmark)

# Test file from "http://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/6/6.006/s08/lecturenotes/files/t8.shakespeare.txt"
text_sample<-readLines("Testfile_Text.txt")
microbenchmark(str_extract_all(text_sample,"\\w+"), times=10)
microbenchmark(stri_extract_all_words(text_sample), times=10)
```

Results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                               expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
str_extract_all(text_sample, "\\\\w+") 426.759 467.0959 496.0429 486.2049 547.1542 572.6955    10
                            expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
stri_extract_all_words(text_sample) 361.3251 388.7932 418.5938 409.8164 454.7217 495.8416    10
```

Comment: Or `stringi::stri_extract_all_words(text_sample)` to do it without using a regex at all, and probably faster.

Comment: Thanks, I learned something new :D